# Flutter: whole app shifted up on linux chrome

Tags: linux, flutter, google-chrome, flutter-web, flutter-web-browser

I've written a Flutter web app that works great on every device I've tested except on Linux Chrome. The app is really slow and laggy and is shifted up half out of the window. But the InkWells or button boxes are still in the correct place. I also get the error in the browser console:

```
WebGl: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid
```

So I tried building the app with just html but it didn't make a difference:

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html --release
```

Comment: This only occurs for me on my laptop. On every other device me or my friends have this does not happen (Linux, Windows, Android, Mac, iOS). With Firefox it worked, only Chromium based browsers seem to have this issue.